# Record and Playback automatically

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am able to record and playback.But these are on click of buttons.

when i click on record it starts recording and when i click on play it starts playing the recorded voice.

But i need to acheive the following:

when i click on record it will start recording and when ever there is a pause it should playback the recorded voice.

example: `how are you john.`(pause) i am fine

click on record it will start recording `how are you john` when there is a pause it should automatically start playing the recorded that is `how are you john.`

how to acheive this please help

Comment: did you find a solution of this problem? I am interested in it too.

Comment: No till now i havent found any solution.

Comment: @Goofy Can't you check amplitude of the audio while recording it?